# R- For loop for non-sequential list

Tags: r, string, for-loop, nonsequential

This is probably a simple question, but I'm struggling finding a way to do the equivalent of "for (i in 1:10){ do something}" but with a list of strings. For example:

given a list of strings a = ("Joe", "John", "George") I'd want to do the following:

```
for (a in "Joe":"George"){
  url <- paste0(http://www.website.com/", a)
  readHTMLTable(url)
}
```

and have the function traverse through the list of names and hit the url with each name. 
Thanks.

Comment: Definitely use `lapply` instead of `for` so your results will be in a list. Also `:` between strings doesn't work; use the variable you stored them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd go with `for (i in 1:length(a)) { etc }` but yeah getting your head around apply functions is generally preferable for speed reasons.

Comment: Idk how I never tried that, worked perfectly, thank you. So would the lapply be something along the lines of

Comment: a <- lapply(table, function(x){

Comment: Sorry, I can't stop hitting enter.

Comment: a <- lapply(table, function(x){  ?? })

Comment: `b <- lapply(a, FUN = function(x) {
    url <- paste0(http://www.website.com/", x)
    return(readHTMLTable(url)) }` would (i think) get you a list of tables, which you could then rbind into a data.frame or whatever. untested though

Answer (score 0):

Use "" in paste0 function

```
a = c("Joe", "John", "George")

for (i in 1:length(a)){
  url <- paste0("http://www.website.com/", a)
      readHTMLTable(url)
}

lapply(a, function(x){paste0("http://www.website.com/", x)})
[[1]]
[1] "http://www.website.com/Joe"

[[2]]
[1] "http://www.website.com/John"

[[3]]
[1] "http://www.website.com/George"

sapply(a, function(x){paste0("http://www.website.com/", x)})

Joe                            John                          George 
"http://www.website.com/Joe"   "http://www.website.com/John" "http://www.website.com/George"
```